# Adding platform Android to Cordova fails but "android" is on PATH

Tags: android, cordova

I am having a really annoying issue when I try to run my cordova project on Android.

When I run the command

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

it fails with following error:

```
Error: Failed to run "android". Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and that the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your PATH.
```

However, I do have the android command in my PATH, and I do have an Android SDK installed:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/<user>/code/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin:/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:<...>
```

I can even run the android command in the shell, and list the installed SDKs:

```
$ android list target
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Running /home/arthur/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager list target

Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-26"
     Name: Android API 26
     Type: Platform
     API level: 26
     Revision: 2
```

My cordova version is as follows:

```
$ cordova --version
4.0.0
```

It has to be this version otherwise this project won't build.

What am I missing here? What do I do to cordova to recognize that the `android` command is actually available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which cordova-android version do you have?. Try to run this command

`cordova platforms android`

Depends which version you have, you need to download an android sdk. For example, cordova-android version 6.2.6 supports Android SDK Tools v26. See [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/05/04/android-release.html).  I suspect that you have an older version of cordova-android, you'll need to install a minor sdk.

Comment: I ran the `cordova platforms android` and it gave me `android 5.0.0`. [This blog post](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/09/cordova-android-5.0.0.html) mentions that it supports the Marshmallow SDK. I then installed the Marshmallow SDK but, while it successfully installed, when I ran `cordova run android`, it failed with the same `Android SDK not found` error.